How to include a separate framework for a combination of configurations and schemes?
So basically I have 2 schemes: prod and staging. And both have their own Debug and Release configuration settings (one of which is the bundle ID, eg. prod/Release: com.mycomp.myApp, prod/Debug: com.myComp.myApp.debug, staging/Release: com.myComp.myApp.staging.debug, staging/Debug: com.myComp.myApp.staging.debug).
Now, there is a framework that is bound to each bundle ID. So I need 4 instances of the same framework for each bundle ID.
I have several targets for the prod and staging. So at least we can differentiate between com.mycomp.myApp* and com.mycomp.myApp.staging*. I was thinking to make 2 more targets so we will have these targets: myApp, myApp-Debug, myApp-Staging, myApp-Staging-Debug.
Also, I copied each frameworks into separate folders like so: \{PROJECT_ROOT}\Frameworks\prod-Debug\MyFramework.xcframework, \{PROJECT_ROOT}\Frameworks\prod-Release\MyFramework.xcframework,
\{PROJECT_ROOT}\Frameworks\staging-Debug\MyFramework.xcframework, \{PROJECT_ROOT}\Frameworks\staging-Release\MyFramework.xcframework.
Also, the framework is not in CocoaPods, Carthage or SwiftPM. It is a precompiled framework that should be manually copied and set.
I'm sure there is a better way than this. What is the best way to do this?
Thank you.
